# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't show cs0012 errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I have a classic scenario.

Type `MySuperType1` is defined in `Assembly1`, type `MySuperType2` is defined in `Assembly2`. `MySuperType2` derives `MySuperType1` and if I wanna use `MySuperType2` in some other assembly I have to reference both `Assembly1` and `Assembly2` or else compiller'll give me cs0012 error (type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced). Agree?

My problem - compiler doesn't show me this error, build looks ok. No errors, no failed project in output window. Build looks ok, so I push it into repository and my coleagues have cs0012. It is very bad for business.

May be there is some setting in Visual Studio that was accidentially set to off. And because of it VS is not tracking such a type of errors? Any other errors are displayed well.

We found, that in VS 2015 error is not shown, but shown in VS 2013

Thx.

Comment: I reckon you're referencing an old DLL, clean solution, re-ref etc etc

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, first I've done - cleaned solution, removed 'bin' folder, close-open VS, restarted PC, removed ref to assembly and added again - didn't help. I created test project and emulated scenario - error is shown. So problem in this certain solution. I already dropped .vs folder - no result.

Comment: Did you check-in the project files as well (.csproj) as these contain the ref's? Not checking in these files your colleagues won't get the reference and will get the cs0012 error you won't see.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, not exactly understand what you mean. When I remove ref, it disappears in .csproj, when I add ref, it appears in .csproj as expected.

Comment: Your colleagues are getting this via source control​? "You push to repository"?

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, yes, via source control. But this error is shown not for all of them. Some of them have the same problem as me

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, I updated description, error is shown in VS2013 and not shown in VS2015

Comment: Run ProcessMonitor and work out which DLL is being used on your affected machine vs the others